# Matlab matrix Multiplication error

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

When I am using the following line of code in Matlab for the multiplication of two matrices

> > multiplied = singleMat * singleMatT;

Then it gives me this error..

??? Error using ==> mtimes
Integer data types are not fully supported for this operation.
At least one operand must be a scalar.

Please help me out for the multiplication of two matrices in matlab..

Answer (score 1):

I guess Matlab doesn't support matrix multiplication of integer matrixes. Try:

```
multiplied = double(singleMat) * double(singleMatT);
```

or

```
multiplied = single(singleMat) * single(singleMatT);
```

if single precision is enough.

Comment: @Mathias  now i am getting this error  >> multiplied = singleMat * double(singleMatT);
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

>> multiplied = double(singleMat) * double(singleMatT);
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.
:/

Comment: How big are your matixes? And do you really want to do a matrix multiplication, or do you want to multiply them elementwise?

Comment: @Mathias they are  18750 X 2 matrices each.. u can say big!! :)

Comment: If you multiply a  18750x2 with a 2x 18750 matrix, you get a  18750x 18750 matrix. With double precision, each element uses (at least) 8 bytes. Thats just shy of 3GB of Data which has to be stored in RAM. Again, do you really want to matrix multiply them or just element wise? (Your variable names indicate, you really want that.)

Comment: I added a single precision version, that saves 50% RAM compared to double. If that precision is sufficient for you. Feel free to mark this question as "answered".

Comment: @Mathias.. yes i want to multiply the matrix with its transpose matrix and then i have to calculate the covariance matrix .

Comment: @Mathias  still the same error :/....  >> multiplied = single(singleMat) * single(singleMatT);
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Comment: How much memory do you have? Do you use a 32 or 64 bit operating system? Windows or Linux?

Comment: Then you better find a system with more RAM. That matrix is still 1.5GB big. Restart the computer, only start matlab and only load the Matrix, try it again. If it fails you're out of luck. Although its possible to only calculate the matrix in pieces, if you want to work with it you have to do all the work in chunks.

Comment: @Mathias Thanks man for your kind Help.. Stay blessed and have a nice day.. :)